# Return a row even though I'm really not supposed to get one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Data

```
region class_month attendance
NY  12/1/2011   70444    
NY  1/1/2012    70125
NY  2/1/2012    69582
NY  3/1/2012    71529
NY  4/1/2012    72468
NY  5/1/2012    67068
LA  3/1/2012    1638
LA  4/1/2012    3079
LA  5/1/2012    4205
```

I want my results to be:

```
  region class_month attendance
    NY  1/1/2012    70125
    NY  2/1/2012    69582
    NY  3/1/2012    71529
    NY  4/1/2012    72468
    NY  5/1/2012    67068
    LA  1/1/2012    0
    LA  2/1/2012    0
    LA  3/1/2012    1638
    LA  4/1/2012    3079
    LA  5/1/2012    4205
```

Query

```
SELECT a.region
    ,a.class_month
    ,CASE 
        WHEN a.attendance IS NULL
            THEN 0
        ELSE a.attendance
        END AS attendance -- this clearly isn't right
FROM dbo.mbo_monthly_attendance a
where class_month between '2012-01-01' and '2012-05-01'
```

How do I make LA return rows with 0 attendance for months in which it had none in the date range provided?

Thanks for a push in the right direction.

Comment: `COALESCE` would be simpler than the `CASE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit 2: I think this will work:

```
select mr.region, mr.class_month, coalesce(a.attendance, 0) as attendance
from (select * from 
 (select distinct region as region from mbo_monthly_attendance) r,
 (select distinct class_month as class_month from mbo_monthly_attendance) c) mr 
LEFT OUTER JOIN mbo_monthly_attendance a 
  ON mr.class_month = a.class_month AND mr.region = a.region ;
```

You could break it up by views to make it more understandable:

```
create view regions as select distinct region from mbo_monthly_attendance;
create view class_months as select distinct class_month from mbo_monthly_attendance;
create view region_months as select * from regions, class_months;

select mr.region, mr.class_month, coalesce(a.attendance, 0) as attendance
from region_months mr LEFT OUTER JOIN mbo_monthly_attendance a 
  ON mr.class_month = a.class_month AND mr.region = a.region ;
```

---

Create a table for 'class month' and use an outer join with the monthly attendance table.

```
create table months (class_month date);
insert into months values ('1/1/2012');
insert into months values ('2/1/2012');
insert into months values ('3/1/2012');
insert into months values ('4/1/2012');
insert into months values ('5/1/2012');
insert into months values ('6/1/2012');

SELECT a.region
    ,a.class_month
    ,COALESCE (a.attendance, 0) AS attendance
FROM dbo.mbo_monthly_attendance a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN months m ON a.class_month = m.class_month 
WHERE m.class_month between @StartDate and @EndDate;
```

Rather than creating a separate table, you could use the attendance table to get all months present:

```
create view months as select distinct class_month from mbo_monthly_attendance
```

Comment: in your first query if both NY and LA have lets say only 3 date values not all, how would you return data for missing 2 dates?

Comment: @rs - yes, it does need that at least one region has a row for the particular month.  The only way around that is to create a table of dates somehow (as in my original pre-edit suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime
set @startdate = '2012-01-01'
set @enddate = '2012-05-01'

;with cte as
(
    select @startdate DateValue
    union all
    select DateValue + 1
    from    cte   
    where   DateValue + 1 < @enddate
), cte2 as
(
    select distinct region, DateValue from dbo.mbo_monthly_attendance a 
    outer apply (select * from cte) x
)


select 
d.region,d.DateValue class_month,COALESCE (a.attendance, 0) AS attendance
from cte2 d
LEFT outer join dbo.mbo_monthly_attendance a
on CONVERT(varchar(15),d.DateValue,101) = CONVERT(varchar(15),a.class_month,101)    
order by d.region,d.DateValue
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```